# What patron would best suit a warlock who struck a pact to get vengeance?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation

The character concept I came up with is a warlock who struck a deal with her patron after the murder of her father and now her sole purpose is finding out who killed him and exacting her vengeance upon them.

If it helps envision what I have in mind I got the idea from the song Blood Red Roses by C21FX

Specifically these lyrics

> A wretch hellbound and bent on blood

and

> Toil begat by father's blood
>
> This path was laid before her
>
> Redemption born by brigand's blood
>
> A blight upon the darkness
>
> The pact embraced, a road unsought
>
> The Maiden of Death won't be unwrought

and

> Vengeance is her only ward
>
> Beware the blood red rose's thorn

I was listening to the song and the idea struck me to make a character based on it but I'm not sure what patron would be the best for her.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not going to touch System/Mechanics here. I think all Patrons and/or Pacts would be available. But here are my thoughts:

Cool song!

I heard Fae influences in the music, so **ArchFey** (PHB) would work. They are known for Deals and Contracts, so a Vengeance-Pact seems to fit.

**Fiend** (PHB): demons and devils would embrace Vengeance as a motive. If it speeds your Soul's path to Hell, they're sure to sign you up!

**Celestials** (XGE) don't seem to fit, for me. YMMV

**Great Old One** (PHB) is too Alien. They care little for the mores of mortals.

**Hexblade** (XGE) is always a good choice! *Pact of the Blade*, and stab your way to victory! Lots of room to fit your story in.

**Undying** (SCAG): Definitely something to work with here. Not even Death can stop your thirst! (*"I will have my vengeance, in this life, or the next!"*)

*"The Pact Embraced, the road unsought"* seems to imply a level of unwillingness, or at least unknowing. Did you know what Bargain you were entering? Fey are tricksy like that!

(PHB) = Players Hand Book. (XGE) = Xanathars' Guide to Everything. (SCAG) = Sword Coast Adventurers' Guide.

Comment: I think Undying is in SCAG. Checking sources now. I have purposely not included UA.

Comment: Thank you for this! This is exactly the kind of thing I needed! Definitely gonna go with Undying here. Also to me the line about "a road unsought" seems to imply more about a taboo-ness than unwillingness or unknowing

Answer (score 4):

## Any of them

The different patrons represent different entities that a Warlock has struck a pact with. That pact consist of an exchange of power (ie. your class features) for some services (work these what these are out with your DM). There are no Patrons that are themed to revenge motivations (unlike that the Paladin Oath of Vengeance) and for any kind of patron a willingness to help in a revenge can be construed.

What you have done in terms of character creation is answer the question:

> What led you to make the pact[?]

Found in the Creating a Warlock section (PHB 106), which along with getting inspired, is a great start, but a not a start that directs you towards one Patron over another.

I realize this is maybe not the answer you wanted, but if you want someone to help you brew up a character, I would recommend finding a forum (you can find our curated list [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/52137)) or join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) where some chatizens (yes, that is a term we use) might be willing to chat about it.